# How to set LOCAL_CODE in gitolite

Tags: 12.04, git

I want to set the LOCAL_CODE variable in my .gitolite.rc. I tried to set `$LOCAL_CODE = "/home/gitolite/.gitolite/local-code";` and the setting from [this](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/cust.html#localcode).

But `gl-query-rc LOCAL_CODE` is empty.

The Link above says that some packages can handle this variable different. How to set it in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get` installed v2 of gitolite and it seems that `$LOCAL_CODE` was introduced with v3. You can either put your hooks into `hooks/common` of use v3 from their git. I choosed the second solution.